# Can Grails Controller name have number in it

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Can I have a grails controller named Office365Controller. More specifically is it allowed to have numbers in controller names? In url mapping i use office365 as controller. Could this be somehow conflicting with camel casing convention used for controller.

I ask this question because when i call a function inside this controller, i get tomcat error 403. My all other controllers are working fine and security for all of them is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I have a grails controller named Office365Controller.

Yes.

> More specifically is it allowed to have numbers in controller names?

Yes.

> I ask this question because when i call a function inside this
>   controller, i get tomcat error 403.

There may be some other factor in your app that is causing the issue, but I don't think the numbers in the controller name would cause a 403.  A controller like this should work fine:

```
class Office365Controller {

    def index() {
        render retrieveSomeValue()
    }

    protected retrieveSomeValue() {
        'hello world'
    }
}
```

It isn't clear what might be going wrong in your app, but the answer to the questions quoted above is "yes".